# Dual-system Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I did dual boot with Windows 7 & Ubuntu 14.04. I get both in boot menu but can't boot into Windows 7. The primary drive where Windows 7 was configured now shows to be logical drive with all files in it. How to resolve it ?

This is what it shows:

```
irshad@irshad-desktop:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk     
├─sda1   8:1    0  58.6G  0 part /media/irshad/B2E08E69E08E339F    
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part     
├─sda5   8:5    0 195.3G  0 part /media/irshad/8E90A6A690A6946D    
├─sda6   8:6    0 182.8G  0 part /media/irshad/7650B08250B04B1F   
├─sda7   8:7    0    25G  0 part /   
└─sda8   8:8    0     4G  0 part     
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I tried to run `update-grub` but I get the following result.

```
$ sudo update-grub 
Generating grub configuration file ... 
/etc/grub.d/06_custom: 31: /etc/grub.d/06_custom: function: not found 
/etc/grub.d/06_custom: 34: /etc/grub.d/06_custom: save_env: not found 
/etc/grub.d/06_custom: 36: /etc/grub.d/06_custom: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

Comment: Please run `lsblk` command inside Ubuntu and edit your question including it's output.

Comment: @KasiyA: no errors.........when i try to boot win 7, it just goes black and again returns to boot menu. That sda1 is considered to be media.........how to change it to primary drive ?

Comment: No no wait..... Did you install windows7 after ubuntu? or not

Comment: @KasiyA: no i dint. I installed ubuntu from win 7.now ubuntu works but not win 7

Comment: @kasiya: its exactly as you edited.

Comment: Did you have edit grub?

Comment: @KasiyA: Yes, i saw some forum and followed. it was last week. Sry forgot to mention i edited grub. i dont e1 know what i followed.......i dont e1 have link......sry for your troubles man........

Comment: You should try to restore Windows bootloader then to restore GRUB. Boot from Windows Rescue CD and run `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot` then follow advices in [this article](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

Comment: @Danatela: i dont have win 7 rescue cd. Can i use rescue cd from someelse's pc ??

Comment: You can use Windows Installation media. It can be either DVD or USB stick. And of coarse you can use _any_ official Windows 7 rescue CD you can find because it doesn't rewrite it's product key.

Comment: It seems the first is the right one… Second should work only in Windows. And I'd not place torrent links here. You can get in trouble.

Comment: thx.......@Danatela..........your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

#### Boot your system using windows 7 installation CD to fix your Windows boot first.

Go to "repair your system" after selecting your language from first dialog.

use command prompt (Troubleshoot ► Advanced Options ► Command Prompt) 

type `bootrec /fixboot` then hit enter

type `bootrec /fixmbr` then hit enter

#### THEN boot from Ubuntu live CD/USB and do below steps to restore your grub:

1. Open a Terminal (use <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Mount `/dev/sda7` (this one you can get from `lsblk` where root `/` partition mounted in) by the following commands: (run one by one)

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
   for i in /sys /proc /run /dev;do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i";done
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
3. And run below command to install grub to main partition `/dev/sda`:

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
4. Update grub and exit and reboot your system.

   ```
   update-grub
   exit
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: my win 7 files are in "dev/sda1 /".......should i still continue to as "dev/sda 7/ mnt" ? and sda 7 is where ubuntu is installed. and i dont think it will have enough space.

Comment: @gambler420 yes Of course! but you need fix your windows first then try to restore grub

Comment: so with your method i will uninstall ubuntu and restore with win 7 ?

Comment: @gambler420 NOooooo I said Use windows 7 installation CD and repair its boot then use Ubuntu installation cd(Select "Try Ubuntu without installation") and restore your Ubuntu Grub boot loader. you don't need to unistall Ubuntu

Comment: will either of these torrent files help me as win 7 recovery disc ? https://kickass.to/windows-7-and-windows-vista-recovery-discs-x86-x64-by-kailash-t5382543.html https://kickass.to/kaspersky-rescue-disk-10-0-32-17-windowsunlocker-1-2-2-usb-rescue-disk-maker-1-0-0-7-12-1-2014-rar-t8571855.html

Comment: You don't have windows 7 .iso image file?

Comment: nope. i installed win 7 like a year b4

Comment: @gambler420 'um use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair I couldn't open your links

Comment: this is the link i got after running repair boot "paste.ubuntu.com/8527832/".

Comment: @gambler420 Still you can not boot Windows 7?

Comment: was away till now......trying now

Comment: Finally booted win 7 with "Testdisk"........thx to you mate for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

At last I booted win 7 by using `Testdisk`. Link to solution if anyone has problem in booting windows even thought all the files are present/intact.

If you have damaged the boot sector of one of your partitions (e.g. by installing GRUB in it by mistake), you may have troubles. For example, if it is a Windows partition, you will not be able to boot into Windows any more.

Remark: if you have this problem, [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) should automatically warn and tell you the name (eg sda2) of the broken partition.

Here is how to repair it:

### Via an Ubuntu disc

#### Step 1 - Boot on a liveCD or liveUSB

Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB, then choose "Try Ubuntu".

#### Step 2 - Install TestDisk in the live-session

Once in the Ubuntu live session, install [TestDisk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TestDisk) this way:

1. Connect internet
2. Open the Software Center, in the top bar click Edit -> Software Sources -> enable the Universe repository
3. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type :

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y testdisk && sudo testdisk
   ```

#### Step 3 - Use TestDisk

1. Via the arrows and the Enter key, go to the [No log] menu,
2. then select the disk where the broken partition is,
3. then select [Proceed],
4. then choose the type of partition (generally [Intel]),
5. then[Advanced],
6. then select the broken partition with [Boot], it will display something like :

   ```
   Boot sector
   Status: Bad

   Backup boot sector
   Status: OK

   Sectors are not identical.

   A valid NTFS Boot sector must be present in order to access
   any data; even if the partition is not bootable.

   [  List  ]  [Backup BS]  [Rebuild BS]  [  Dump  ]
   ```
7. Check that you have "Status ok" below "Backup boot sector"
8. select [Backup BS].

Done

### Via a Windows disc

This method is only able to fix the bootsector of a Windows partition.

1. Get a Windows recovery disk, as explained on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader)
2. Boot on it, and use the 'fixboot' command (not the 'fixmbr' one). This should fix the bootsector of Windows.

[source: Ubuntu official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix)