# Can't Boot into Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair, mbr

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop with Windows 8 installed.
Now I can boot into Ubuntu without any problems, but I can't boot into Windows 8.
After I choose Windows 8 Loader (on sda1), It direct me to the same grub screen.

I have tried boot-repair using recommended repair option and this is the result.

> "Boot successfully repaired Please write on a paper the following URL:
>   http://paste.ubuntu.com/8544452/
>
> ... Please repair the bootsector of the sda1 partition ... this can be
>   perforn such as TestDisk "

Comment: Read [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/533974/dual-boot-win-7-and-ubuntu-14-04/534189#comment730091_533974) and then see this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/534189/283843

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason grub has damaged your Windows boot record.

To install and run testdisk open terminal and enter `sudo apt-get install -y testdisk && sudo testdisk`

For help using testdisk look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix#Step_3_-_Use_TestDisk). And for additional information check out the forum post [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1926510).

You will probably need to run boot-repair one more time after the damaged Windows boot partition has been fixed with testdisk.